# Convergence of Series with Ratio Test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+(x-n)^{2}}$$ converges for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

I am having difficulty solving this using the ratio test.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+(x-n)^{2}} =\sum_{n=0}^{k}\dfrac{1}{1+(x-n)^{2}} +$$

$$\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+(x-n)^{2}} $$ where $k$ is an integer larger than $x+1$.

The first sum is no problem.

The second one $$\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+(x-n)^{2}}\le  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+n^{2}}$$

Which is convergent.

Comment: @zz20s Thanks for the edit.

Comment: No worries. Great answer!

Comment: I think this answer is good, but I fail to recognize the ratio Test in it. To me it looks like Comparison Test, which is fine too

Comment: Correct, I did not use ration test. I found comparison easier way to go.

Comment: I actually think the ratio test is inconclusive, since $$\frac{1+(x-n)^2}{1+(x-(n+1))^2}$$ converges to $1$.